# how to save x and y coordinates when doing a right click in C#

Tags: c#, winforms

my goal is to open a ContextMenuStrip on right click remember this click x and y and then on clicking on one of the given items to do something till now this is what i have done:

```
public delegate void mydelegate(string s);

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    m_MyContextMenuStrip = new ContextMenuStrip();
    m_MyContextMenuStrip.Opening += new System.ComponentModel.CancelEventHandler(cms_Opening);
    this.ContextMenuStrip = m_MyContextMenuStrip; 
}

void cms_Opening(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
    m_MyContextMenuStrip.Items.Clear();

    location1 = m_MyContextMenuStrip.PointToClient(new Point(0, 0));
    location = m_MyContextMenuStrip.PointToScreen(new Point(0, 0));
    // Populate the ContextMenuStrip control with its default items.
    m_MyContextMenuStrip.Items.Add("-");
    m_MyContextMenuStrip.Items.Add("Apples");
    m_MyContextMenuStrip.Items.Add(location.X.ToString() + "and  " + location.Y.ToString());

    m_MyContextMenuStrip.Items.Add("aaaa", null, new EventHandler(onaaaClick));
    // Set Cancel to false. 
    // It is optimized to true based on empty entry.
    e.Cancel = false;
}

private void onaaaClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //will handle the click on aaa

    Form2 f2 = new Form2(functodel);
    f2.Show();
}

void functodel(string s)
{
    Label l = new Label();
    l.Text = s;

    l.Top = location.Y - 108;
    l.Left = location.X - 100;
    //l.Left = this.Location.X - location.X;  

    l.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
    this.Controls.Add(l);
    l.BringToFront();
}
```

where Form2 is:

```
private mydelegate m_del;

public Form2(mydelegate del)
{
    m_del = del;
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    m_del(textBox1.Text);
    this.Close();
}
```

my problem is when i click on the right click i am not getting the location i want, i am getting another location. can someone explain to me what am i doing wrong ?

1. how to get the right location.
2. how to get a ContextMenuStrip where i had only once an item?
3. let's say on the given label i am righting i want to click on the right click and get another optiones then in m_ContextMenuStrip (delete item and change color) how do i do that?

**Edit:**

I would try to explain my motivation better

my goal is a picture where you click on the right click on coordinate(x and y ) openes for you a there a menu(menu1) just like you do on windows desktop the menu top left is the coordinate you have clicked and from this coordinate a menu is opened (just like i want to change or open something on the desktop it doesn't opened in the left top corner of desktop it's opened where I have clicked  ).

when the aaa item is clicked i want another form to be opened and from there with the delegate open new label form1
now when this label is clicked with right click i want another menu to be opened (let's call it menu2)

menu1 and menu2 are different creatures

I might have missed the main concept?

Comment: Your question isn't clear to me. You should try to explain better what you want to do, perhaps adding some images...

Comment: I can answer (more or less) to only the first question: in your `location` variable, you're saving the top-left corner coordinates of your `m_MyContextMenuStrip` (the screen coordinates). What `"right location"` do you need ?

Comment: @diEmAll you have a new edit whom explain the motivation maybe my start was all wrong so I think it would help you understand me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could access the **mouse coordinates** and calculate that to the point of your picturebox (in this test a panel)?

You would calculate it on the opening event of the menustrip.

And **MousePosition** is a static property on the *Control* class.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form {

    private void pnlClickOnMe_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
        Point mouseLocation = MousePosition;
        // get point of mouse relative to pnlClickOnMe
        Point pointYouAreInterestedIn = pnlClickOnMe.PointToClient(mouseLocation); 
        lblShowCoordinates.Text = string.Format("{0} - {1}", pointYouAreInterestedIn.X, pointYouAreInterestedIn.Y);
    }

    public Form1() {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    #region designer
    private void InitializeComponent() {
        this.lblShowCoordinates = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.pnlClickOnMe = new System.Windows.Forms.Panel();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        this.lblShowCoordinates.AutoSize = true;
        this.lblShowCoordinates.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(32, 18);
        this.lblShowCoordinates.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(35, 13);
        this.pnlClickOnMe.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ActiveCaption;
        this.pnlClickOnMe.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(31, 64);
        this.pnlClickOnMe.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(206, 152);
        this.pnlClickOnMe.MouseClick += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.pnlClickOnMe_MouseClick);
        this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(284, 262);
        this.Controls.Add(this.pnlClickOnMe);
        this.Controls.Add(this.lblShowCoordinates);
        this.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.PerformLayout();

    }

    #endregion

    private System.Windows.Forms.Label lblShowCoordinates;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Panel pnlClickOnMe;
}
```

Comment: When you downvote it's always nice to know **why** you downvote ;)

Comment: @ Stomemet it wasn't me , another Q let's say i want another m_MyContextMenuStrip1 for another item in the same panel can you help me with that ?...

Comment: Don't really see the problem. Just do it the same way you do it currently, but with a new contextmenustrip?

Answer (score 1):

Did you use the designer to build your forms ?

It's pretty easy to do what you need, without any coding effort.
Look at this link for more info:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173080%28VS.80%29.aspx

Anyway, about context menus:

**1.**
You don't need to find mouse position and open the menu manually.
Just set the `ContextMenuStrip` property of your picturebox to your context menu like:

```
pictureBox.ContextMenuStrip = yourContextMenuInstance; 
// you can do this also from Designer
```

and when you right-click on a pixel in the pictureBox, automatically your menu will appear in the right position (I mean in the mouseposition).

**2.**
If your menu items don't depend on menu position or some other changeable status, you can add them at menu creation and not in the `Opening` event handler.
The same is for the `ItemClick` handlers, you can attach them at items creation.

**3.**
Maybe you don't need this feature, but you can add submenus to any item in your context menu.

---

So, to resume:

in your `Form1` you need to create (by designer, or code as you wish) a `PictureBox` (let's call it `pbox1`), a `ContextMenu` (let's call it `menu1`) and your `aaa` item, with its corresponding event handler.
Hence, set `pbox1.ContextMenuStrip = menu1` and in the aaa click event handler you can open you `Form2`.
Then, you can previously define you `Form2`, in the same manner of `Form1`, i.e. with its contextMenu attached to the textbox etc...